# jax-rs : How to validate pathparam and return bad request if it is not the proper type?

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-8

I have this endpoint:

```java
  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  public Response getActiveById(
      @PathParam("id") @NotNull(message = "id may not be null") Long id) {
    try {
      AccountDTO accountDTO = accountService
          .getActiveById(id);
      GenericEntity<AccountDTO> accountDTOGenericEntity = new GenericEntity<AccountDTO>(
          accountDTO) {
      };
      return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(accountDTOGenericEntity).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
      return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
          .entity(new ErrorInfo("ACCOUNT_SERVICE", "ACCOUNT ID NOT FOUND") {
          }).build();
    }
  }
```

And when someone passes a string it returns 500 internal server error but I wanted to return 
400 bad request. I would not like to change the type of the parameter because the right type is long. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That's odd that you are getting a 500. The specification states that any error in parsing a `@PathParam` should lead to a 404.